# Query Data from Existing SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/
Created db with SQLite Database Browser, put db file in "assets" folder etc..

Then i add this method to end of DataBaseHelper class;

```
  public ArrayList<market> getMarkets(String table) {

    ArrayList<market> markets = new ArrayList<market>();
    market mrkt = new market();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table, null);

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            mrkt.market_id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("marketid"));
            mrkt.market_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            mrkt.market_telno = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("telno"));
            mrkt.market_location = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("location"));
            mrkt.market_hours = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hours"));
            markets.add(mrkt);
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return markets;
}
```

and try to show markets on listview with these lines in main activity class:

```
 dbh = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
 markets = new ArrayList<market>();
 marketListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMarkets);

 markets = dbh.getMarkets("markets");



 // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
 ArrayAdapter<market> arrayAdapter =      
 new ArrayAdapter<market>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, markets);

 // Set The Adapter
 marketListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

my layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewMarkets"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:dividerHeight="0.1dp"
    android:divider="#0000CC"
    >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

However, i got error, "unfotunately application has stopped"..
I'm new in android, anybody can help me ?
Thanks.

Here logcat:

```
04-09 16:32:00.125: W/dalvikvm(17103): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41685c80)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103): Process: com.example.deneme, PID: 17103
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.deneme/com.example.deneme.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: markets (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM markets
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: markets (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM markets
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at com.example.deneme.DataBaseHelper.getMarkets(DataBaseHelper.java:165)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at com.example.deneme.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
04-09 16:32:00.130: E/AndroidRuntime(17103):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: post logcat and is your database is made? have you find it in data/data folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
dbh = new DataBaseHelper(null);
```

`null` is not a valid `Context` reference that `SQLiteOpenHelper` requires. Replace with `this` to use the activity as a context. This is the reason for the NPE in `getDatabaseLocked()`.

Comment: Yepp, i edited: new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());  and updated logcat

Comment: You didn't post the part from sqlite open helper where you create the table, but do try uninstalling the app first in case there's an older version of the database file around.

Comment: I created same way as in tutorial link. Put created file in "assets" folder...  Logcat says "no such table". I can not understand where is the mistake :/